# Конфигурирование apache2/odbc/FreeTDS

Tags: ubuntu, sql-server, apache2, php7, unix-odbc

Всем привет, что имеется:
Ubuntu server 16.04, Apache2.4, FreeTDS, php7.0
PHP использует pdo_odbc чтобы через FreeTDS делать запросы к MS SQL SERVER 2008.

Проблема с кириллицей, в выдаче вместо нее только знаки вопросов.
При этом если скрипт запускать не через web-сервер, а через консоль в операционной систем, то все символы кириллические отображаются. Т.е. мне кажется, что проблема с настройкой Апача.
Буду очень благодарен, если кто-то поможет с решением.

Answer (score -1):

Вам непременно поможет конвертация вашей базы в Latin (не SQL, а той, в которую вы всё это парсите), тогда все `?????` станут прекрасно отображаться.